# SAS y and X intercept of a logarithmic curve

Tags: sas

I have a time series which looks at lifetime value over time and has a logarithmic trend line.  The trend line continues to grow daily but the growth lessens as time goes on.

In order to automate my excel trend line ideally I need to calculate the X and y intercept for the trend line in SAS. But I'm using WPS in SAS language.  Does anyone have any advice how to calculate the y and X intercept in SAS using the slightly more limited WPS.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, but it's where I might start - take a log transformation and then do a linear regression. Then get the predicted values for x=0 and y=0 based on the formula? You have two questions here - one is methodology and the second is how to implement that method.

Comment: We're going to need more information to be able to answer the question. Can you provide a sample dataset and screenshot of what you are looking at so we can give you the most appropriate answer? With WPS, you should be able to do this.

Comment: Hi All thanks for your help here- after all the searching on google It was as simple as a log transformation to get the correct results .  Thank you for your help :)